# How to use CCTargetedTouchDelegate in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I wanted to subclass `CCSprite` in order to add dragging functionality on sprites in `COCOS2D-X,` thats why i wanted to use `CCTouchDelegate` with it.

but the error i am getting is about redefinition of the delegate methods.

well.... the delegate method are meant to be redefined, aren't they?

I guess i must have done something wrong somewhere but couldn't find it.

My code is as follows.

**.h file**

[image: .h file]

```
namespace mygames
{

    class DragSprite: public cocos2d::CCSprite, cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate
    {
        public:
        DragSprite* createWithFile(const char *pszFileName);
        bool isTouchingOnSprite(cocos2d::CCPoint  touch);

        private :
        bool isDrag;
        cocos2d::CCPoint whereTouch;
    };
}
```

**.cpp file**

[image]

```
#include "DragSprite.h"
using namespace mygames;

DragSprite* DragSprite::createWithFile(const char *pszFileName)
{
    DragSprite *pSprite = new DragSprite();
    if (pSprite&&pSprite->initWithFile(pszFileName))
    {
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(pSprite, 0, true);
        pSprite->autorelease();
        return pSprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pSprite);
    return NULL;
    }

    bool DragSprite::isTouchingOnSprite(cocos2d::CCPoint  touch)
    {

        if (this->boundingBox().containsPoint(touch)) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }

    }
    bool cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
    {

    }
    void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
    {

    }
    void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
    {

    }
    void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchCancelled(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
    {

    }
```

**CCTargetedTouchDelegate class**

[image: CCTargetedTouchDelegate]

```
class CC_DLL CCTargetedTouchDelegate : public CCTouchDelegate
{
    public:
     /** Return YES to claim the touch.
      @since v0
     */
     virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) { CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);return false;};

     // optional
     virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
     virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
     virtual void ccTouchCancelled(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
 };
```

**CCTouchDelegate class**

[image: CCTouchDelegate]

```
class CC_DLL CCTouchDelegate
{
    public:

    CCTouchDelegate() {}

    virtual ~CCTouchDelegate()
    {
    }

    virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent); return false;};
// optional

    virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
    virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
    virtual void ccTouchCancelled(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}

    // optional
     virtual void ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouches); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
     virtual void ccTouchesMoved(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouches); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
     virtual void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouches); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}
     virtual void ccTouchesCancelled(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent) {CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouches); CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);}

};
```

**JUST OUT OF CURIOSITY :-**

since i am already inheriting from CCTargetedTouchDelegate
i.e my class syntax is 
    class DragSprite: public cocos2d::CCSprite, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate
    {
    }

Do i still need to make use of scope resolution operator in the error generating code
i.e

```
bool cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchCancelled(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
```

can't i just write like the following ? is it gonna make any difference ?

```
bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
void ccTouchCancelled(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

}
```

Are the required delegates still gonna be called ?

because i can see the errors gone , if i do this.

Comment: Instead of screenshotting your code, please copy and paste the relevant sections here. That'll make it far easier for us to help you.

Comment: I answered your post on the Cocos2d-x Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the methods in your DragSprite class, you need to use that class' prefix.

Instead of re-implementing the classes in the cocos2d namespace/class:

```
void cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDel....
```

you need to implement the methods in your own class like so:

```
void DragSprite::CCTargetedTouchDel....
```

Comment: Not working.. I have replaced the METHODS in my .cpp file by bool DragSprite::CCTargetedTouchDelegate::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    
} but still it gives the same error

Comment: I also changed class syntax FROM "class DragSprite: public cocos2d::CCSprite, cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate" TO "class DragSprite: public cocos2d::CCSprite, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegatecocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate"